# SSR getServerSideProps NextJS with Firebase/Firestore

Tags: firebase, next.js, server-side-rendering

hope you all have a great day! this week i'm starting to learn more about nextJS, and today, i got stuck about this thing called SSR, idk why but when i pass the props it always return undefined, seems like it didn't even populated, but when i try to `console.log`, the data is there

here's my `code`

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  // Fetch data from external API
  try {
    console.log("HEI WE ARE HERE");
    console.log(query.pid);
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("mycollection")
      .doc(query.pid)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const dataX = [];
        if (querySnapshot.exists) {
          dataX.push(querySnapshot.data());
        }
        console.log("CEK DATAX: " + JSON.stringify(dataX));
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert(err);
      });
    // Pass data to the page via props
    return { props: { dataX } };
  } catch (err) {
    return { props: {} };
  }
}
```

and this is my `function Page()` looks like

```
export default function Page({ dataX }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log("CEK PAGE DATAX: " + JSON.stringify(dataX));
```

if you see on my `function Page()`, in console.log, here's the result in my browser
[![screentshoot1][1]][1]

and console result in my `getServerSideProps` looks like this
[![screentshoot2][2]][2]

as you can see, that in my `getServerSideProps` my `dataX` is not empty, but when passed, it become undefined :(

somebody please help..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8ply.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy5ZB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that in the following part, the variable `dataX` is defined in the Promise callback, but you used it in the outer scope. You should return `dataX` in the `.then(() => {})` callback, and lastly do `return { props: { dataX: ref } };` instead of `return { props: { dataX } };`.

```js
const ref = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("mycollection")
    .doc(query.pid)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const dataX = [];
        if (querySnapshot.exists) {
            dataX.push(querySnapshot.data());
        }
        console.log("CEK DATAX: " + JSON.stringify(dataX));
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        alert(err);
    });
// Pass data to the page via props
return { props: { dataX } };
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, i've tried your advice, [please see this image](https://imgur.com/a/cV0Df6g) , but i got new error looks like this `Reason: object ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.`

Comment: Oh yeah, you should do `const ref = await firebase...` so that you get a proper JSON object instead of Promise<> or something like that.